# What is the proper way to access a model function from another model in CI4?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, namespaces, codeigniter-4

I am converting an existing open source application from CodeIgniter 3.x framework to CodeIgniter 4.x framework.

According to the documentation I need to do the following steps:
[image]

Here is an example of one of my models

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

/**
 * Sale class
 */
class Sale extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get sale info
     */
    public function get_info($sale_id)
    {
        $this->create_temp_table(array('sale_id' => $sale_id));

        $decimals = totals_decimals();
        $sales_tax = 'IFNULL(SUM(sales_items_taxes.sales_tax), 0)';
        $cash_adjustment = 'IFNULL(SUM(payments.sale_cash_adjustment), 0)';
        $sale_price = 'CASE WHEN sales_items.discount_type = ' . PERCENT
            . " THEN sales_items.quantity_purchased * sales_items.item_unit_price - ROUND(sales_items.quantity_purchased * sales_items.item_unit_price * sales_items.discount / 100, $decimals) "
            . 'ELSE sales_items.quantity_purchased * (sales_items.item_unit_price - sales_items.discount) END';

        if($this->config->item('tax_included'))
```

The problem I'm facing is that after doing this, PHPStorm is giving me a warning on `if($this->config->item('tax_included'))` telling me "Property accessed via magic method"

Per the CI4 documentation I added `$this->config = new Config();` but PHPStorm then complains about `$this->config` telling me "Property declared dynamically" and suggests I add a private variable called $config... I don't think that's what I want.  It also complains about Config() saying "Undefined class Config"

I tried also adding the following above the class declaration:

```
/**
 * Sale class
 * @property Config config
 */
```

But I get the same complaint that Config is not a valid class.

The Config model is located under app\Models\Config.php which is the same directory this model is in.

Comment: I would declare `$config = new Config('File');` and then `$config->property` in your controller. Thats what I would do

Answer (score 0):

```
$mymodel = new MyModel();
```

I would recommend to use service layer and entity call service in your ctl.